# How can I test URI equality without respecting query parameter ordering

Tags: perl, uri, equality, query-string

I would like something like [`URI::eq`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI#URI::eq(-$first_uri,-$other_uri-)) except such that the canonical forms of the the URI that are compared ignore the query parameter ordering,

```
print URI::eq(
  q[http://a.a/?a=1&z=2], # a before z
  q[http://a.a/?z=2&a=1]  # z before a
);
```

I would like this return true.

Comment: Split URI into components and compare each element individually, also check that number components is matching for both URIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could normalize the query.

```perl
use List::Util qw( pairs );

$uri->query_form([
   map { $_->[0], $_->[1] }
      sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] || $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
         pairs
            $uri->query_form
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting the query parameter keys as a list ( for example using URI::QueryParam ), sort it and compare ( one could use Data::Compare ).

If they're identical, you'll have to compare the values for each key.

Keep in mind that this is not necessarily trivial, the values could be JSON,
which you'd have to first decode or make sure it's canonical,
so a straight forward 'eq' is likely going to lead to false negatives.

Having decoded JSON, you'll end up with a fairly arbitrary data structure ( serializable, at least ). Now eq may be good enough for your purposes, or it may not, again depending on your needs ( is an empty string the same as no value? Is 0 the same as 0.0 ? etc. ).

Your example seems to indicate that you've not considered this, so perhaps you don't need it, which would make this quite simple: simply 'eq'-compare all of the values. Or you've underestimated the problem, in which case you may want to ask another question or post additional information.

I am not aware of a module that does this, personally, but I'd be happy  to learn there is one!